# How to find IP of my server for Microsoft's Cloud

Tags: service, cloud

I created tcp ip application and published it to cloud of Microsoft, but for now I don't know how to find the IP of my server.

Or in another words, how can I find the IP at which implemented role was deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether you are trying to get the public IP or the private IP of the server.

If you want to reach this server from outside of the Azure network, then you are looking for the public IP. In this case you must [define an InputEndpoint for your role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433020.aspx). You'll be required to specify a FQDN for your app. You can find the IP address of this FQDN using the usual methods like tracert, ping, etc.

If you want to reach this server from within the Azure network, typically you'd want some other role in your tenant to communicate with this server, then you'd need to [define an InternalEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432980.aspx) for your server. You can then use the ServiceRuntime library to discover the private endpoint of your role instance.

[Enabling Communication for Role Instances in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180158.aspx) is an excellent resource to get a better understanding of how this works.